# Conditionally removing DEBUG during uglifyjs task on Grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I would like to remove my DEBUG statments at build, and I noticed on  http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/compress I can define `global_defs: { DEBUG : false }` to remove anything wrapped in a debug clause `if (DEBUG) {}`

My uglify task doesn't seem to remove any DEBUG section, any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using grunt-contrib-uglify v0.3.3

Here is my **grunt task:**
...

```
uglify: {
   ...
   simple: {
       options : {
          mangle: false,
          compress: {
            global_defs: {
              DEBUG: false
            },
            dead_code: true
          }
       },
       files: {
          'yayMin.js' : [ ..., somefile.js, ... ]
       }
   },...
...
```

**somefile.js**

```
...
    if (DEBUG) {
       console.log('epic fail - fix your build');
    }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also check out [grunt-groundskeeper](https://github.com/Couto/grunt-groundskeeper) which removes pragmas written like this:

```
// <debug>
doSomething();
// </debug>

// <validation>
performSomeValidationOnlyNeededDuringDevelopment();
// </validation>
```

It also has options to remove calls to `console.log()` and `debugger;` statements.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug in grunt-contrib-uglify that only removes the global_defs from one file. I noticed DEBUG statements would be removed, as requested by options, if I reduced my files to one file

Did not work:

```
 ...
 files: {
          'yayMin.js' : [ ..., anotherfile.js, somefile.js, anotherfile2.js, ... ]
       }
 ...
```

Worked:

```
...
files: {
          'yayMin.js' : [ somefile.js ]
       }
...
```

Final Grunt Task

```
uglify: {
'build-minify' : {
        options: {
          mangle: false,
          compress: {
            global_defs: {
              DEBUG: false
            },
            dead_code: true
          },
          wrap: true
        },
        files : {
          'justSayNoToDebug.js' : [
            'ahHaveDebugsInMe.js'
          ]
        }
      },
```

Comment: ughhhhhhhhhhhhhhh that's awful